# How to pass by pointer a multidimentional vectors using pointers in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I want to print the values of the multi-dimensional vector `a` using pass by pointer. Can anyone please let me know what is wrong in my program? I am getting a lot of errors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class foo{
    private:
    vector <int> v;
    public:
    foo(vector<vector <int> >**);
};

foo :: foo(vector<vector<int> >** a)
{
    cout << a[0][0] <<endl;
    
    //cout<<a->size()<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> a{{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8}};
    foo f(&a);
    
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the errors you are getting. You aren't passing by reference you are using pointers so you need to use `(*a)[0][0]`

Comment: @AlanBirtles That was a silly mistake, sorry.

Comment: It looks like you've been reading about arrays and are trying to apply what you read to vectors.  Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). (And there is absolutely no reason to use a class here.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Actually this class structure is used in a different program that I am writing. Yes this class is not needed here but I need this concept in a different program. And yes I am tryng to replicate the multi dimensional array thing in vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing some things here:

- `vector<vector<int> >**` is a pointer to a pointer of `vector<vector<int> >`.
- In `foo f(&a);` the expression `&a` is `vector<vector<int> >*` (pointer to vector of vectors of int)
- A reference would be `vector<vector<int> > &`.

You would have `foo` like this:

```
//     Reference here VVV
foo(vector<vector<int> > &a)
```

and simply call like this:

```
foo f(a);
```

(*without* taking the address of `a`)